# Where can I find a listing of LDAP Active directory messages and there meanings?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, distinguishedname

I am getting the error:

> LDAPException: Invalid Credentials (49) Invalid Credentials
>   LDAPException: Server Message: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9,
>   comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
>   LDAPException: Matched DN:

Where is a list that lists:

- Server Message: 80090308 and meaning?
- LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9 and meaning?
- data 52e, v1db1 and meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a specific listing. The first number (49) is a standard Windows error code. You can use this tool http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985 to look them up. Ignore the part about "Exchange".

The server message is also an error code - same tool as above.

DSIDs are pointers to the file and line number in the AD source code, so, without access to that it's not useful. Finaly the last two tidbits are just internal data from AD itself.

Comment: I got the program you mentioned to work for 49, but not 80090308.  What command line did you use?

Comment: Try `err 0x80090308`. It's possible that sometimes the errors aren't in the tools database also.

Answer (score 18):

Even I haven't yet the LDAP source of codes, indeed this will help you:

LDAP Error Code 49

Symptoms
Users are unable to log in. The following appears in the atlassian-confluence.log:
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 701, v1db0]

Causes
There could be many reasons for this issue. Please check the error code (in the example above, it's 701) and match it with the description in the following table:

Error Code  Description

525 user not found

52e invalid credentials

530 not permitted to logon at this time

531 not permitted to logon at this workstation

532 password expired (remember to check the user set in osuser.xml also)

533 account disabled

701 account expired

773 user must reset password

775 user account locked

In the example above, the error code is 701 (account expired).

published at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/User+directory+sync+fails+with+LDAP+Error+Code+49

Comment: @Emerald214: anyway, you can follow alternate links offered in same broken link page.

Answer (score 0):

"52e" for "data" means invalid credentials. Your username seems correct but password is not correctly authenticated. (Refer to link and details shared by Jorge above)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the right Upper/Lower case:
MYCOMPANY\myuser (as I was doing it with javascript, I had to use MYCOMPANY\\myuser