# Extract data value from a LDAP error message

Tags: c#, regex

I have an exception of kind `DirectoryServicesCOMException` and I need to extract the data value from it's `ExtendedErrorMessage` property.

Here is a sample test from the `ExtendedErrorMessage` property:

`8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0904DC, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 701, v1db1`

I need `701` from the string.

Just for reference, I found these messages from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024909/481656

I have success by using LastIndexOf 'data' and the next ',' after LastIndexOf 'data' combo but looking for a cleaner solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the result you want always before the last comma and it is only numbers, you can use [`String.Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration and [`Regex.Match(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0904DC, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 701, v1db1";
string[] array = s.Split(new []{','},
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
string s1 = array[array.Length - 2]; // This will be " data 701"
string finalstring = Regex.Match(s1, @"\d+").Value; // \d+ is for only integer numbers
Console.WriteLine(finalstring); // Prints 701
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/Rs1ECV)</kbd>.